# Conditions in class attribute of element in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use this code:

```
<buton class="audio-button {{audio.isPlaying && 'active'}}"></button
```

Is this practice are normal or it will make problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to add the *active* class if `audio.isPlaying` is true. In that case, you should be using `ng-class`.

```
<button class="audio-button" ng-class="{ 'active' : audio.isPlaying }"></button>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: Whatever you prefer I guess. I like the `?` here because I feel it is more semantically understandable. Also in the latest perf I ran, the ternary was twice as fast.

Comment: Interesting. In any way you forgot false declaration in your answer.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't paying attention when I replied. I have updated my answer to be much more angular correct. Thanks for keeping me honest, haha.